# Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove: $x^2 \in H$ for every $x \in G$ iff every element of $G/H$ is its own inverse.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups, abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$.
>
> Prove: $x^2 \in H$ for every $x \in G$ iff every element of $G/H$ is its own inverse.

Here is my proof.  I've only tried proving one way so far, please indicate if I'm on the right path.

If $x^2 \in H, \space \forall x \in G$, then $x^2 = h_1$ for some $h_1 \in H$.

So, $$x=h_1x^{-1}$$ $$x \in Hx^{-1}$$ $$Hx=Hx^{-1}$$

Therefore $G/H = \{Hx:x=x^{-1}\}$

Is this correct?

Also, since $G/H$ is the group $G$ with $H$ factored out, and since $x^2 \in H, \forall x \in G$, does this mean $G/H$ is the group that does not include the elements in $G$ whose square is in $H$?  If this is so, I don't understand because if $y \in G/H$ then $y=y^{-1}$ and so $y^2=e$, but $e \in H$.  So $G/H$ still has an element whose square is in $H$.

Comment: Minor quibble:  the usual definition is $G/H = \{ gH \mid g \in G \}$, the set of **left** cosets.

Comment: @SammyBlack By definition of a normal subgroup, left cosets and right cosets are the same thing...

Comment: @Goos True, but most books use the left cosets by default.

Comment: I also thought left and right cosets were equal.  My book uses the right coset, Im using A Book of Abstract Algebra - Pinter. Now I know left cosets are more standard.

Comment: Any takers on my other question regarding my intuition on $G/H$?

Comment: @JohannFranklin They are equal, so you can use whichever you prefer when the subgroup is normal. It's really just a minor detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of your proof looks correct to me. The cosets in $G/H$ are on the form $aH$, where $a$ is not the square of some element in $G$.

For the other direction, you want to consider that $xH = x^{-1}H$. This happens, by definition iff $(x^{-1})^{-1}x \in H$, so $x^2 \in H$. This is just the definition of two cosets being equal.

For your intuition about the factor group, if $yH \in G/H$, then $yH = y^{-1}H$, so $G/H$ contains only elements who are their own inverses. What you are doing when you take the factor group is like setting $x^2 = e$ for all $x \in G$, so you are 'forcing' every element to be its own inverse.

Comment: I've never truly understood biconditional statements? Why don't people just do the same proof in reverse?

Comment: Can't that be done in this proof? I start with my last line and go backwards?

Comment: @JohannFranklin You can, yes, but just writing it as an iff statement makes the proof more compact. People generally prefer math to be written very compactly, and doing the same proof in reverse is unnecessary. The biconditional tells the reader that the proof reads in both directions without you having to write it down.

Comment: @JohannFranklin I added some intuition about what the factor group means.

Comment: $G/H$ is basically $G$ minus the elements of $G$ whose square is in $H$? So $G/H$ is forced to be the elements of $G$ whose square is $e$?  Is this right? Please elaborate because $e$ is in $H$ so $G/H$ still has one element in $G$ whose square is in $H$.

Comment: @JohannFranklin $H$ contains the square of every element in $G$, right? And when we take the factor group, what happens is that every element in $H$ is set to $e$ (as $H$ is the identity in our factor group). So we are setting $x^2 = e$ for every element in $G/H$. Hence every element in $G/H$ has to be its own inverse.

Answer (score 1):

in general if $G/H$ has index $n$, then $x^n$ belongs to $H$ for all $x$ in $G$.